# how to create a procedure to my update statement along with exception handling

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an update statement which is updating 5 million records, in the procedure i simply wrote as below.

```
create procedure test_item_update begin update statement; end;
```

Now my question is whether i can simple write like this without any error handling.

I am new in learning `MySQL`, getting many things in
mind in handling writing the `procedure`. please assist the way i need
to write procedure with following best practices. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Error Handling in MySQL. Check this URL :http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/

Comment: oops sorry am using ms-sql...

Comment: proper indentation , code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exception using TRY...CATCH as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_item_update
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        /* Write your code here */
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        /* Write code here to handle the error */
    END CATCH;
END
```